# Connect to a DBF

Tags: c#, database, dbf

Well, I'm developing a program where I have to connect to a DBF, but the problem is, I need to grab some data from DBF and put in textbox, such as ID, User name .... (These data that are stored in DBF), but how can I do this?
I thought of using IDX, but could not create the index in C #

And for the database connection, I am using the following command line:

```
OleDbConnection con = new OleDbConnection("Provider=Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0;Data Source=C:\TEMP\;Extended Properties=dBASE IV");
```

Well, how can I do to get the information from DBF, and do searches on it, something like:

```
SELECT * FROM TESTE.DBF WHERE NOME='Alex'
```

Thanks
Alexandre

(* Sorry for my terrible english *)

Comment: Question, is this a MS Access DataBase file..? if so why are you using  Properties=dBASE IV

Comment: add a @ infront of your provider you ave return characters in your string here is an example for starters 
OleDbConnection con = new OleDbConnection(@"Provider=Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0;Data Source=C:\TEMP\

Comment: I was able to do so in Python, here's ho I did it http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13994584/reading-dbf-files-with-pyodbc/14046178#14046178 is this file generated with MS Access? or Visual FoxPro?, you can try using the VFP OLEDB Provider