# Opening a Visual FoxPro DBC file in Python

Tags: python, database, visual-foxpro

I have an old system that I'm working on that uses Visual FoxPro so I was wondering if there's any way I can access the .DBC file using Python 3.6.4 in order to create reports for it.

I've read using dbfread but that only looks at one table at a time and preferably like to look at multiple at once.

Is there any modules or methods that I could use to not only look at but also edit this database?

Comment: Question 1) do you need to access Data Tables (DBF's) within a VFP DBC?   Or do you need to access 'Free' Data Tables (DBF files) ?

Comment: Question 2)  Have you looked at:   https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13994584/reading-dbf-files-with-pyodbc   or others referenced at:   https://www.google.com/search?ei=svinWs7-Dpi4jwOls7FY&q=python+odbc+vfp&oq=python+odbc+vfp&gs_l=psy-ab.3..33i160k1.10944.12077.0.12422.4.4.0.0.0.0.145.377.3j1.4.0....0...1c.1.64.psy-ab..0.4.375...0j0i22i30k1j0i22i10i30k1j33i21k1.0.-lSs-9avO34

Comment: In my opinion, Dhugalmac's comment provides the best answer to this question.  I went to the link and it does seem to provide a solution.

Comment: Thanks so much @Dhugalmac! I couldn't find that question on here but that had the answer