# How to use Python to export Visual FoxPro Database into other DB?

Tags: python, visual-foxpro, dbf

I'm trying to extract all the data from a NetYield database (built on Visual FoxPro) - have a bunch of .dbf files and a .dbc file.

I assume the .dbc file has the relationships and all the names properly, and want to try to extract this to ANY database (will be happy with CSV or Access or MySQL) to work with the data.

Eventually, this will be ported over to a new ERP system (SAP Business One).

I have tried using Software Solutions, but they are expensive and the Trials don't seem to have retained the relationships between the tables (but I could be wrong, and the full-price solutions would - unfortunately, don't have the ability to approve budget items on my own to buy it and test it out).

Have tried some Python code from the thread: [Reading DBF files with pyodbc](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13994584/reading-dbf-files-with-pyodbc)
But, it's a 'bit beyond my understanding (more of a JS / Java developer here)

```py
import dbf
from glob import glob

dbf.Table()

for dbf_file in glob(r'C:\users\Bijan\OneDrive\AAF\NetYield\070719_133749\*.dbf'):
    with dbf.Table(dbf_file) as table:
        dbf.export(table, dbf_file)
```

I'm expecting a perfect relational database as the output - but I will be happy with building those relationships myself, as long as I can get the data out of the current format into something more modern.

Thank you

Comment: The code looks good -- is it giving errors, or just not enough structure for your needs?

Comment: dbc is the database container, dbf are tables. Provided, database doesn't have code to protect tables, you can use VFPOLEDB. Transferring plain tables is the easy part. In a VFP database, referential integrity is maintained with a series of RI code in the database. Your best bet would be to use VFP and some code to perform the export to say postgreSQL, MySql, MS SQL Server ... (but not to access, which would be nonsense of course).

Comment: @CetinBasoz Thank you for the information - and  yes, access would be a poor choice, but it's the current business standard (although we're moving away from it). Do you have any recommended super basics on VFPOLEDB - how to start, how to use, or anything that will give me the fundamentals?

Comment: With Python I don't have an idea. I can give you code with VFP, VBA, C#, and Go if that would do for you. If you have access as a business standart (pity) then you should already know VBA and OLEDB.

Comment: Definitely don't know OLEDB, while my VBA isn't bad, it's not great either, and I'd prefer to be building technology and systems that can be accessed from other simpler (think GUI) methods - for when I'm no longer around. Any help in getting this data out, even if it means doing it in a different way..... I wish I knew how to write/execute code for VFP, but have no clue.